Layout builder + multilingual
I'm currently working on translating a D10 site based on Layout Builder to other languages. As I want the layouts to be the same in every language, but displaying just a translated version, I don't think that LB Asymmetric Translation contrib module would be an option here.
Quickly I thought of LB Symmetric Translation module, but I realised that it was an alpha version and not updated since 2022. Reading at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2946333 it seems that LB Symmetric is not an option anymore, so...
Does anyone know if there is a stable way to get translated pages, using layout builder + block types, but preserving the layout in different languages?

How exactly are you using Layout Builder?  If you use layout builder to customize the appearance of a node, for example, that layout will be applied to all translations automatically by default, so there's nothing you need to do or install to get the behavior you want.

For most content types, that's our way to go... but for Landing pages the default layout is blank, and the page uses components (block types I mean) to be built. Due to content maintainability, that's why I consider important having the same layout in different languages.

I don't understand the question. Are the blocks translated? If you have a layout of translated blocks, they will be translated into the relevant language automatically.

No, they're not translated. We have an English site, and most pages have been created through blocks created directly in node/[nid]/layout. As we're adding the languages now to make the site multilingual, none of them are translated, but we would like to preserve the layout structure for other languages. We need exactly what LB Symmetric translations contrib pretends to do, because by default, once you translate a node, the Layout option is not there to manage the layout of the translation (to translate its blocks).

Hmm, I didn't realize you could create blocks in Layout Builder.  Blocks created in the UI at /admin/structure/block can be translated, and those blocks can be placed in Layout Builder.  However, with that approach, I guess you would have to recreate all your blocks.  Paragraphs can also do this, but you would have to recreate all your Layout Builder layouts in paragraphs, which is probably even more work.  Another option would be to use content types with fields and then place the fields (not blocks) in Layout Builder.  This is what I would do, but it doesn't meet your requirement.

How anything gets added to Drupal core in the 2020s without full multilingual support is entirely beyond me.
However, it looks like Translation Management Tool is on the cusp of solving this and i very much hope the merge request to resolve that issue (always also available in patch form) works for you.

Thank you! Good references to start with.
EDIT: sent by error ^^u     Currently I made LB Symmetric translation to work with some patches. I feel the same as you, have no idea on how Layout Builder inline blocks + Multilingual does not get along well with just Drupal core.
